# Getting error OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'alarms_2022-02-01 18:39:58.173215.json' in python

Tags: python, json, datetime, binary, append

Could you please help me on solving below error.

I wanted the file name to have the date and time in it while its getting saved. The file is saving "data" value.

I used this its working. But i wanted date and time as well.

```
file_name = f"alarms_{int(time.time())}.json"
with open(file_name,"ab") as file:
    file.write(data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your resulting filename `alarms_2022-02-01 18:39:58.173215.json` is not a valid Windows filename (it contains `:` colons).

Try formatting the `datetime` to something more sensible, like this:

```py
...
file_name = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("alarm_%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.%f.json")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Turn datetime to string before writing to file name. Make a new variable called `date_string`. This method keeps the date and time information.

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = f'{datetime.datetime.now():%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S%z}'
```

Step 2:
Also make sure there is no space by replacing space with underscore`_`.

```
date_string = date_string.replace(" ", "_")
```

Step 3:

```
file_name = f"alarms_{date_string}.json"
with open(file_name,"ab") as file:
    file.write(data)
```

Comment: A colon won't work in a filename at least on some OS. Also, why replace a character that you could just remove in the format string?

Comment: Appreciate it. Its resolved :)